# How does Spotify mask the audio URL and also prevent download of song mp3

Tags: javascript, audio, spotify

I'm looking to mask the audio playing on my site so people can't download the audio files and also don't know what the url for the actual file (mp3) is

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer,

### YOU CAN'T

If they are listening to your audio, they **have it already**

> You can slow them down but can't stop them.

The only thing you can do is obfuscate the process. But why bother at all?

---

The browsers were designed to: Serve content - which means give the content to the user. To show you how easy it is, here's how I usually grab video/audios on virtually any streaming site:

Prepare the network tab of your preferred browser debugger and let the video/audio load. Then look for it in the loaded resources. Videos are usually streamed in .flv or .mp4, and audio in .mp3. When you spot the url, open a new tab/window and open the link there. The browser will then download the file.

Comment: I just tried to on Spotify with Flashgot Extension on Firefox and all I get is a scratchy sound and it stops...even though file size is **3.8mb** and type says **.mp3**. Am I doing something wrong?